# import Delphi Dll in Ansi-C

Tags: c, delphi, dll

I wanted to know if somebody have experience with `PChar` var in Delphi.

I have a module (programmable resistor) which is communicating with this function:

```
int resCommand(int anH, char* pstr, char *Var);
```

If I will get data from the resistor, I need to read `*Var`. In the description of the module 
they describe this prototype:

```
function rbResiCommand(aHandle: integer; aData: pChar; VAR aResult: pChar): integer;
```

The problem is how can I handle the pointer `Var aResult` because I need the strings from `Var aResult` from the Delphi dll?.

Also I have here an Out Parameter, so is this possible to implement in ANSI C?

My code:

```
VarResult[255]; 
char *pResult; 

pResult = VarResult;
get = rbResiCommand(aHandle, "GET0", VarResult);
printf("Read Data from Channel 0: %s", VarResult);
```

Comment: This needs to be a lot clearer. I cannot tell whether you are implementing C or Delphi. Whether you are calling the function or implementing it. Whether PChar is PWideChar or PAnsiChar. Who allocates and deallocates what memory. What thee text encoding is. What the calling convention is. I suggest you work to improve the question.

Comment: I can tell you that `VAR aResult : pChar` does not match `char*`.

Comment: What is `VarResult[255];`? Looks like, **in C**, it would default to `int VarResult[255]`, and that is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Rudy It's not the actual code. It's fake code. Or code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @David: I know. That is why I ask. If people don't post their real code, there is no way we can find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration in C:

```
int resCommand(int anH, char* pstr, char *Var);
```

Is equivalent to this declaration in Delphi:

```
function resCommand(anH: Integer; pstr: PAnsiChar; Var: PAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl;
```

Notice the use of `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar` (`PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar` in Delphi 2007 and earlier, but is an alias for `PWideChar` in Delphi 2009 and later), and the explicit `cdecl` calling convention.

This declaration in Delphi:

```
function rbResiCommand(aHandle: integer; aData: pChar; VAR aResult: pChar): integer;
```

Is equivalent to this declaration in C:

```
int __fastcall rbResiCommand(int aHandle, Char *aData, Char** aResult);
```

Notice the use of `Char` (uppercase `C`) instead of `char` (lowercase `c`), an extra level of indirection on the last parameter, and the different calling convention (`__fastcall` instead of `__cdecl`).

`Char` (uppercase `C`) is a C++Builder `typedef` for Delphi's native `Char` type, and will map to `char`, `wchar_t`, or `char16_t` as needed, depending on compiler and RTL version.

`__fastcall` in this case only works in C++Builder, which is compatible with Delphi-specific features.  No other C/C++ compiler support's Borland's flavor of `__fastcall`. Microsoft's `__fastcall` is something else - C++Builder supports it as `__msfastcall`).

Assuming the calling convention was simply omitted in the `rbResiCommand` documentation and really is `cdecl` in the DLL, and that the DLL was written in a version of Delphi where `PChar` maps to `PAnsiChar`, then your C code should look like this:

```
int __cdecl rbResiCommand(int aHandle, char* aData, char** aResult); 

...

char VarResult[255]; 
char *pResult = VarResult;
get = rbResiCommand(aHandle, "GET0", &pResult);
printf("Read Data from Channel 0: %s", VarResult);
```

In either case, this is assuming the DLL is merely filling in the array you supply to it (in which case, the extra indirection was not necessary) and not allocating its own memory and returning it to you to use (which the extra indirection is commonly used for).  If it is allocating memory, then you need to get rid of your array:

```
int __cdecl rbResiCommand(int aHandle, char* aData, char** aResult); 

...

char *pResult = NULL;
get = rbResiCommand(aHandle, "GET0", &pResult);
printf("Read Data from Channel 0: %s", pResult);
// free pResult however the DLL requires you to free it...
```

Comment: `System::Char` is not C. Nor are references. It is exceptionally likely that `__fastcall` is not used here, either the MS version, or the Borland version.

Comment: This `__fastcall` is only valid in C++Builder. The `__fastcall` of Microsoft and most other Windows compilers is different and not compatible with the one used by Delphi. So one should, in Delphi, either use `cdecl` or, preferrably, `stdcall`.